# Excel VBA get date from a string

Tags: excel, vba

If I have a cell with the following:

```
Tuesday, April 16th 2009
```

How do I convert that string into a date format recognized by Excel. I think I have to use MID() and FIND() functions.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here is a function that would work from VBA and as a User Defined Function

```
Function GetDate(InString As Range) As Date
    Dim newDate As Date
    Dim tmpDate As String

    'Sample Date
    'Tuesday, April 16th 2009

    'Remove the Day of the Week.
    tmpDate = Trim(Mid(InString, InStr(InString, ",") + 1))

    'Get rid of "th"
    tmpDate = Replace(tmpDate, "th ", " ")

    'Get rid of "rd"
    tmpDate = Replace(tmpDate, "rd ", " ")

    'Get rid of "nd"
    tmpDate = Replace(tmpDate, "nd ", " ")

    'Get rid of "st"
    tmpDate = Replace(tmpDate, "st ", " ")

    'Convert string to date
    newDate = DateValue(tmpDate)

    GetDate = newDate
End Function
```

Comment: Thanks, the script worked well. I modified because in spanish the date is written different. For example: 'Tuesday, April 16th 2009' is 'Martes, 16 de Abril de 2009'. So as you can see there is no 'th','rd or any of those characters. So instead of removing them, I change the script to remove 'de'. Worked like a charm.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that text is in A1, we can break it out into separate parts, and use `DATEVALUE` to put it together.

```
B1: =MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+2)-FIND(" ",A1))
B2: =IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+2),3)),VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+2),2)))
B3: =RIGHT(A1,4)
B4: =DATEVALUE(B2&" "&B1&" "&B3)
```

Or, you can do it in one go:

```
=DATEVALUE(IFERROR(VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+2),3)),VALUE(MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+2),2)))&" "&MID(A1,FIND(" ",A1)+1,FIND(" ",A1,FIND(" ",A1)+2)-FIND(" ",A1))&" "&RIGHT(A1,4))
```